# Does "wash together" have a figurative malevolent meaning?

Tags: word-usage

I mean like in the following sentence made up by me:

> XYZ washed science sceptics and flat-earthers together.

Here, "washed together" would mean "conflate", with the conditions that science sceptics and flat-earthers are not the same group, but XYZ wants them to look like they are one group.
I don't know if this meaning doesn't exist or there are just too many results about clothes and that's why I can't find any related examples by internet search.

Comment: to wash together is usually for actual clothes, people or things. One idiom is: put x and y in the same basket.

Comment: We can _tar two things with the same brush_, if you mean _say they have the same faults or bad qualities_.

Comment: The word "washed" (as in launder) would be taken metaphorically.  The science-sceptics and the flat-earthers are made of similar "fabric". But it's not an established idiom. I don't see any malevolence, unless you hear in  "washed" echoes of The Great Flood.

Comment: I have rarely seen 'washed in the same stream' used to mean 'having many of the 
 qualities of, or very similar to, or related to, something' e.g. that _type of anguish that's washed in the same stream as madness_

Comment: I've voted to close the question.  When you "make up" a sentence, you must have a meaning in mind.  So what is the meaning that you want to convey.  Perhaps there is context that will help understand what your metaphor is.  As it is, I don't know what "they" refers to, or how you metaphorically imagine "they" can wash these people together. Perhaps you mean that the sceptics and flat earthers were put in contact and so some ideas from one transferred to the others. Since you made it up, it is not common figure of speech. This needs more details and more context.

Comment: I su;ggest "... they conflated ..."

Comment: @JamesK I did an edit, and used the word Jack O'Flaherty suggested.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó  I meant for "conflate" to replace "washed together", not to explain it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a metaphor, it should carry meaning from sense to another. When you wash shirts and socks together, you don't "conflate" them. So there isn't the sense of "conflate" to carry across. So this doesn't work as figurative language.

To me "washed together" would allude to the way that colours can "run" in the wash, and the colour of a red sock (for example) could transfer to a white shirt, making it pink. This could carry across to the metaphorical sense of ideas and beliefs of one group transferring to another.

There are other phrases such as "lump together" "put in the same basket" or just use the more formal "conflate".

Comment: OK, now I see that this can't have the meaning in English as in Hungarian: there it can mean that one wants to make believe that a thing is like another thing, as in your example: coloures can "run" in the wash, and the white shirt turns into not just pink but red (well, theoretically at least).

Comment: @DávidLaczkó - Often, the red shirt becomes less red, and the white one more so. The change can be mutual. People, or groups of people can _cross-fertilise_ each other with ideas.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Definitely, that's another way of using the phrase.